# Sending Emails From Ktor Application

Tags: ktor

I'm currently creating my application using Ktor Netty Engine

I searched the docs for any feature to handle sending emails when a user sends a request to my server but found nothing.

```kotlin
post("/api/v1/auth") {
    // TODO send email when request is sent!
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a java dependency available to be used in Ktor apache-email-commons

```kotlin
implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-email:1.5")
```

And then using an SMTP server e.g. Gmail:

```kotlin
val email = SimpleEmail()
email.hostName = "smtp.googlemail.com"
email.setSmtpPort(465)
email.setAuthenticator(DefaultAuthenticator("email-account", "account-password"))
email.isSSLOnConnect = true
email.setFrom("sender-email-account")
email.subject = "email-subject"
email.setMsg("message-content")
email.addTo("target-email-address")
email.send()
```

Comment: You have to turn off "Less secure app access" if you use smtp.googlemail.com, otherwise you'll get "Someone just used your password to try to sign in to your account from a non-Google app". In addition, this setting is not available for accounts with 2-Step Verification enabled. This approach works, but it's less secure than OAuth2 via web-services.

Comment: As of May 2022, google no longer supports "Less secure app access" for non-paid workspace accounts.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in feature in Ktor for sending emails.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/jakarta.mail):

implementation("com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:2.0.1")

it's newer than the Javax Mail library

Example code in Kotlin:

```kotlin
    import com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException
    import jakarta.mail.*
    import jakarta.mail.internet.InternetAddress
    import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage
    import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
    import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
    import java.util.Properties
    import java.util.Date

    companion object {
            const val GOOGLE_SMTP_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
            const val ZOHO_SMTP_HOST = "smtp.zoho.in"
        }
        private val props = Properties().apply {
            this["mail.smtp.host"] = ZOHO_SMTP_HOST
            this["mail.smtp.port"] = "587"
            this["mail.smtp.auth"] = "true"
            this["mail.smtp.starttls.enable"] = "true"
        }
        private val emailUsername = System.getenv("EMAIL_USERNAME") ?: throw IllegalStateException("EMAIL_USERNAME env should not be null.")
        private val emailPassword = System.getenv("EMAIL_PASSWORD") ?: throw IllegalStateException("EMAIL_PASSWORD env should not be null.")
        private val fromEmail = System.getenv("FROM_EMAIL") ?: emailUsername
    
        private val session: Session = Session.getInstance(props, object : Authenticator() {
            override fun getPasswordAuthentication(): PasswordAuthentication {
                val username = emailUsername
                val password = emailPassword
                return PasswordAuthentication(username, password)
            }
        })
        override suspend fun sendEmail(emailMessage: EmailMessage): Boolean = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            return@withContext try {
                val message = MimeMessage(session)
                val from = fromEmail
                message.setFrom(InternetAddress(from))
                message.setRecipients(
                    Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    emailMessage.to.lowercase().trim()
                )
                message.subject = emailMessage.subject
                message.sentDate = Date()
                message.setText(emailMessage.body)
                Transport.send(message)
                true
            } catch (mex: MessagingException) {
                println("send failed, exception: $mex")
                false
            } catch (e: MailConnectException) {
                println("email send failed, exception: $e")
                false
            }
            catch (e: java.net.ConnectException) {
                println("Connection failed: $e")
                false
            }
            catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                println("Unhandled exception while send email ${e.javaClass.name} from ${e.javaClass.packageName}")
                false
            }
        }
```