# ktor send email with html template

Tags: email, apache-commons, ktor, hbs

I am wondering what is the correct way of sending HTML templates with ktor via email.
This answer  [Sending Emails From Ktor Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66571524/sending-emails-from-ktor-application) can help inline HTML, or simple string but not hbs or other templates which can be used in ktor.

email service will work, but I do want to use a template. And doing it via MustacheContent will not work

```
package com.meet.utils.email

import com.meet.utils.Constants
import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator
import org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail

fun sendForgotPasswordEmail(token: String, emailTo: String) {
    val email = HtmlEmail()
    email.hostName = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
    email.setSmtpPort(587)
    email.setAuthenticator(
        DefaultAuthenticator(
            "apikey",
            "API_KEY"
        )
    )
    email.isSSLOnConnect = true
    email.setFrom(Constants.EMAIL_FROM)
    email.subject = "Forgot Password"
    email.setHtmlMsg("<html><body><div style='background:red;'>Hello</div></body></html>")
    email.addTo(emailTo)
    email.send()
}
```

What I want to do is

```
email.sendTemplate(MustacheContent("forgotPassword.hbs", mapOf("token" to token)))
```

how I can send this?
`resources/templates/reset.hbs`

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>Please visit the link below to reset your password</p>
    <a href="http://localhost:3000?token={{token}}">Reset your password</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compile and render a template via a Mustache factory to get an HTML string. Here is an example:

```
val factory = DefaultMustacheFactory("templates")
embeddedServer(Netty, port = 3333) {
    install(Mustache) {
        mustacheFactory = factory
    }

    routing {
        post("/") {
            val content = MustacheContent("forgotPassword.hbs", mapOf("token" to "my-token"))
            val writer = StringWriter()
            factory.compile(content.template).execute(writer, content.model)
            val html = writer.toString()
            // Send email with an HTML
        }
    }

}.start(wait = true)
```

Comment: it is cool, but it will no apply  styles from head  tag